# Upgrade SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I used to have SQL Server 2008, I have upgraded to SQL Server 2012. However, when I go to attach a database, in this case AdventureWorks 2012, it won't let me attach it and says that it can't attach a 706 version because it only supports 661 and earlier.

I assume the server is still 2008, even though the application says 2012. I have run the `SELECT @@VERSION`, and it confirms that it is a 2008 database, I just don't know how to upgrade this server to 2012. I want to be able to open/attach new databases.

Any help would be great.

Comment: How exactly did you upgrade to SQL 2012?

Comment: Did you upgrade the existing instance, or did you create a new **instance** (with a separate instance name) for SQL Server 2012 ?

Comment: They way i upgraded my sql server 2012, was i just downloaded the new 2012 software and installed it via the setup.exe. I chose the first option under installation, Create new SQL server standalone installation. I also tried to just Upgrade it via the last option in the installation, however when i tried to do that i kept getting an error when it tries to installs features (no features available to transfer)...hmmmm